# Reset or remove MySQL password

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp, mysql

I reinstalled MySQL and now it is asking for the current password.

Is there a command or method with which I can remove the password?

Answer (score 0):

The passwords for MySQL are stored within the "Mysql" database within MySQL itself.

They are in the mysql.user table (column "Password").

You would need to move the database files themselves to another location before reinstalling MySQL.

If you don't want your existing databases you can just delete the files.

I'm not sure where they get put on Windows.  The files are *.MYI, *.MYD and *.frm if you want to search for them.

Answer (score 0):

The database(s) are not deleted if you uninstall MySQL. 
Additionally you have to delete the directory `C:\ProgramData\MySQL` which contains on Windows 7 systems by default the database files (as long as you don't have specified a custom location).

See also: [What steps do I need to take to completely uninstall MySQL?](https://superuser.com/questions/225826/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-mysql)